# how can I increase the width of the textbox of 'File Name' Field

Tags: html, css

I inherited a web app and I want to simple increase the textbox width of 'File Name' Field and tried multiple CSS code but I'm not able to increase it. below is my current update.

CSS

```
    </style>
                .custom-file-input {
                    width: 100%;
                }
                #file-name {
                    width: 80%;
                    max-width: 500px; 
                }
                #file-name::placeholder {
                    text-align: center;
                }
                #file-name {
                    width: 80%;
                    max-width: 500px;  
                }
                #file-name::placeholder {
                    text-align: center;
                }
            </style>

            <form action="/display" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="file-container">
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file" name="file" onchange="updateFilename(this)">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Choose file</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 dropdown-container">
                            <label for="file-name" class="nowrap"><i class="fas fa-file"></i> File Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control space-below wider-textbox" id="file-name" name="file_name" value="{{ file_name }}" disabled style="width: 100%;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 dropdown-container">
                            <label for="group-select" class="nowrap"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Group:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="group-select" name="group" disabled>
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="DIA" {% if group == 'DIA' %}selected{% endif %}>DIA</option>
                                <option value="BBB" {% if group == 'BBB' %}selected{% endif %}>BBB</option>
                                <option value="CCC" {% if group == 'CCC' %}selected{% endif %}>CCC</option>
                                <option value="DDD" {% if group == 'DDD' %}selected{% endif %}>DDD</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 dropdown-container">
                            <label for="template-select"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i> Template:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="template-select" name="upload_table" {% if not table_html %}disabled{% endif %} style="background-color: #ffffe4">
                                {% for template in template_options %}
                                <option value="{{ template[1] }}">{{ template[0] }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="upload-container">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="display-btn" onclick="enableUploadButton()"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Display</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

expected output.

make the field name textbox wider.
[image]

Comment: `col-md-12` above the label/input for File Name?

Comment: @SimonWeber here ?

                        `<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 dropdown-container">
                                <label for="file-name" class="nowrap"><i class="fas fa-file"></i> File Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control space-below wider-textbox" id="file-name" name="file_name" value="{{ file_name }}" disabled style="width: 100%;">
                            </div>
                        </div>`

Comment: yes. If that doesn't work you have to share your css-framework(is this bootstrap?) and/or the css for the used classes.

Comment: the Field name and Text box moved to center

Comment: Your still missing a bunch of css classes, but my guess would be to remove the `max-width: 500px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to improvise a bit to get this working, but this should do the trick:

- Set `col-md-6` to `12`
- Remove unsused CSS selectors and `max-width: 500px`

```css
label {
  width: 20%;
}
#file-name {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="/display" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Added d-flex and align-items-center to mimik your style -->
    <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center">
      <label for="file-name" class="form-lable nowrap"><i class="fas fa-file"></i> File Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control space-below wider-textbox" id="file-name" name="file_name" value="" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```